# How to use BreezeJS with a WCF Data Service cross origin?

Tags: wcf, odata, breeze

I'm using BreezeJS to access a WCF Odata service in my application.  It works great when accessing the service on my local machine, but when I try to run the app against the service on my dev web server, it fails.

The first thing I did was to add headers to the service response to allow cross-origin requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, MERGE, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion
```

Also I set the datajs requests to use JSONP as such:

```
            var oldClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;
            var myClient = {
                request: function (request, success, error) {
                        request.enableJsonpCallback = true;
                    return oldClient.request(request, success, error);
                },
            };
            OData.defaultHttpClient = myClient;
```

My breeze setup is:

```
 breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'odata', true);              
 this.dataService = new breeze.DataService({
      serviceName: 'http://mydevserver/AirVision.Web.Site/AvDataService.svc/',
      hasServerMetadata: true,
      useJsonp: true,
 });
 this.manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: this.dataService });
```

That *mostly* works. However, it blows up if I try to use an expand():

```
this.loadSites = function() {
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("SourceSite")
                  .expand("SourceParameter")
                ;
                return this.manager.executeQuery(query);
            }
```

I get an error from breeze:

```
"TypeError: undefined is not a function
at setNpValue (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:5189:41)
at defaultPropertyInterceptor [as _$interceptor] (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:4913:13)
at descr.set [as System] (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:16161:22)
at protoFn.initializeEntityPrototype.proto.setProperty (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:16034:32)
at updateRelatedEntity (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:14774:26)
at mergeRelatedEntity (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:14715:13)
at http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:14698:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at updateEntity (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:14696:41)
at mergeEntity (http://localhost/AirVision.Web.Site/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:14667:13)"
```

I've stepped through the breeze.debug.js and it comes down to this line:

```
var siblings = newValue.getProperty(inverseProp.name);
```

On that line, the newValue object (which represents one of my data entities) does NOT have the getProperty function defined.

Is there something I need to do, either on the server side or in the javascript client, to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the metadata does not properly define your relationship from 'SourceSite' to 'SourceParameter'.  I've had this error before when there was a problem with the metadata and breeze couldn't find the entity/relationship to serialize the data to.
I would start by ensuring you the relationships, and the entity 'SourceParameter' for that matter, are properly defined in your server side breeze metadata.

Comment: Could be the metadata, but I suspect something else since it works locally.  The cross origin problem also happens if I run against my local machine using the machine name in the service url (since the browser is pointed to localhost, it believes this to be cross origin).  At the moment I am coding around the issue by requesting the tables separately instead of using expand.